# Is it possible to cross the Naruto Strait on foot?

Tags: japan, sightseeing, walking

I’m considering a trip across Awaji Island and on to Shikoku. The [Naruto Strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto_Strait) between these two islands is well known for the whirlpools that occur when the tide is right. As the [Oonaruto Bridge (大鳴門橋)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Cnaruto_Bridge) (that crosses the strait) itself is less than 1 km across, it seems most convenient to walk across for the best view of the whirlpools underneath.

However, while Wikipedia mentions being able to walk onto the bridge from its southern end (to see the whirlpools), I have not been able to find out if the walkway crosses the bridge or if it ends halfway. So: Is it possible to cross the bridge on foot or do I need to resort to a bus or taxi?

Comment: If you head out that way, I recommend taking a look at Otsuka Museum of Art :-)

Comment: @John I don’t think that I would in any way enjoy it but thanks for the recommendation anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ends halfway (450 meters out of 1629 to be precise).

https://japan.stripes.com/travel/naruto-whirlpools-bridge-nature%E2%80%99s-beauty-1547825829

> About the bridge The Ō-Naruto Bridge is a suspension bridge spanning
> the Naruto Straight between Minami-Awaji Awaji Island and Ōge Island
> in Naruto, Tokushima. The bridge opened in 1985, and is 1,629 meters
> long. It connects Shikoku to Honshu via a motorway over Awaji Island
> and the Akashi Kaikyo Bridge.
>
> Uzu-no-michi The Ōge Island end of the bridge has a very special
> feature. A 450 meter long corridor named Uzu-no-michi has been
> constructed in the support girders under the bridge to allow people to
> walk right out over the ocean and view the Naruto Whirlpools. The
> corridor has glass windows all the way along, with four viewing spaces
> where the glass extends from the floor to the ceiling, and floor
> windows at intervals.
>
> At the end of the corridor there is a spacious observation gallery
> where you can enjoy 360 degree views of the Strait. The observation
> gallery also has large floor windows so you can look straight down at
> the swirling ocean 45 meters below. The views of the sea and islands
> are fantastic, even apart from the whirlpools. I also really enjoyed
> watching the boats that bring tourists to cruise around the pools

Comment: Note also that admission to the walkway is (currently) ¥510.

Comment: Bear in mind that the whirlpools are tidal, so you can't just waltz up and expect to see them at any time.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I mentioned that in the question already ;)